# Detect what is selected (highlighted) or clicked within an element on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, selection

How would one go about detecting what has been selected on a page in a browser? Example: Click, hold, select 3 words and 1 image on a page, release.

Sub-question: How to detect what letter someone clicked on?

Without using: A span injector breaking everything up OR a WYSIWYG plugin

I'm hoping this isn't just a type of browser interaction you can't detect.

There could be many uses, but my goal is a simple 'live' page editor, or at least a way to know what someone is clicking on/selecting aside from just the id of an element.

Answer (score 3):

[`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getSelection) is what you need in all major browsers except IE < 9, which has a different API. `window.getSelection()` returns a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection) ([spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#selections)) object from which you can extract a [DOM Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range) ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-range)) representing the selection.

For IE < 9, you can look at [`document.selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or use a library such as my own [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy), which provides the same standards-based API in all major browsers.

Comment: Perfect, thank you :) Any idea how to detect what letter was clicked, without any selection?