# Disable a user from selecting text in input

Tags: jquery, css

I admit I'm a bit stumped why this is not working.

I have an input that I am masking and that is working perfectly, however it seems if you select the text then it 'reveals' the real value.

To solve this, I would like to disable the user from being able to highlight the text in the input. Before you say this is bad usability, I'm working on touchscreens only and this will really just stop it from highlighting if they click too many times.

I have tried putting

```
-webkit-user-select: none;  
 -moz-user-select: none;    
 -ms-user-select: none;      
 user-select: none;
```

on both inputs, but it still wants to select. Is there any other way to accomplish this? This is all I could find when searching around.

and here is a fiddle to play with. http://jsfiddle.net/gtom9tvL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it this way you could make use of `pointer-events: none` on the lower input and `text-indent: -9999px` to remove the unmasked text from the viewport.

**Drawback**

- No carat in the input  (though this could be simulated with javascript, I guess)

---

I would use: `<input class='value' type="password" />` so that the text can not be selected with `ctrl + a` and copy pasted.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/y1kh75ma/3/)

CSS

```
.num {
    position: relative;
}
.value {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
.number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I never even thought of text indent...I guess I only think of that when I'm doing background-images.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without disabling text selection completely, would be to detect the text selection, then de-select it or set the focus to another element.

See: [Detect what is selected (highlighted) or clicked within an element on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403345/detect-what-is-selected-highlighted-or-clicked-within-an-element-on-a-page)

Comment: Te only issue I find with this is that I am handling sensitive data and I don't really want it selecting and revealing those numbers and then deselecting. I do actually have text selecting disabled for most of the app already...it's just this one input that wants to be difficult.

Comment: Also, I kind of need the focus on that element because that is what they are interacting with and there is basically one question per page...so there really is nothing else to focus on.

Comment: I don't understand how selecting text would "reveal" something that is hidden, unless you're simply putting white-on-white, and that's a poor way to hide something to begin with.

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle I provided and you can see what was happening. I am working with a touch screen so my options are a bit limited to what I can and cannot do also requirements from above make it challenging. If you can think of a better way to mask an input field then I would like to know. When I asked the question here the best anyone could come up with is three separate input fields.